# creating backup table using procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

suppose I have two tables `t1` and an identically structured table `bak_t1`.Table `bak_t1` already has some rows from `t1`.Now I want to create MySQL stored procedure that when executed inserts only those rows from `t1` to `bak_t1` which are left to be inserted on `bak_t1` and doesn't reinsert previously inserted rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM` construct like below using `EXISTS`

```
insert into bak_t1
select * from t1 where not exists (
select 1 from bak_t1 where some_id_column <> t1.some_id_column);
```

You can as well use `LEFT JOIN` for this purpose like

```
insert into bak_t1
select t1.* from t1 
left join bak_t1 where t1.some_id_column = bak_t1.some_id_column
where bak_t1.some_column is null;
```